# Travis-CI error with "eval pod install"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, cocoapods, travis-ci

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

script: 
    xctool -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

While Travis-CI is building the project it says:

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.4
$ xcodebuild -version -sdk
$ pod --version
0.34.4
Installing Pods with 'pod install'
$ pushd .
~/build/GabrielMassana/ProjectName-iOS
$ pod install
```

While installing pods the error is:

```
The command "eval pod install" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
The command "eval pod install" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
The command "eval pod install" failed 3 times.
The command "pod install" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that adding this lines solves my problem.

```
before_install:
    - rvm use system
    - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'
```

So my final `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

before_install:
   - rvm use system
   - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'  

script: 
    xctool -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Now cocoapods finish installing.

Probably some Travis machines are set up to run with an old version (0.34.4)

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)