# Travis-CI error with __nonnull

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, travis-ci

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

before_install:
   - rvm use system
   - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'  

script: 
    xctool -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

While Travis-CI is building the project I've got multiple errors like:

```
- (instancetype __nonnull)initWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *__nullable)configuration NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
                ^
- (instancetype __nonnull)initWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *__nullable)configuration NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
  ^
```

So Travis Xcode is complaining about something related to `__nonnull`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem I'm forcing the Travis Xcode to be version 7.2 with this line in the `.travis.yml` file:

```
osx_image: xcode7.2
```

So my final `.travis.yml` file is:

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7.2

before_install:
   - rvm use system
   - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'  

script: 
    xctool -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

As I said in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187769/1381708), `sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'` also forces Travis to use the desired Cocoapods version

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)